# How to make categorical time-series predictions in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I've done some time-series forecasting in R with ARIMA, which predicts a value at a future timepoint given a series of continuous values, but I'm not sure how to approach time-series prediction when dealing with categorical values.

Given these simple training sequences for 5 people's morning dress routine, how can I generate predictions for the final two entries for person6?

```
person1 <- c("underwear", "socks", "pants", "shirt", "tie", "shoes", "jacket")
person2 <- c("underwear", "pants",  "socks", "shirt", "tie", "jacket", "shoes")
person3 <- c("socks", "underwear",  "pants", "shirt", "tie", "shoes", "jacket")
person4 <- c("underwear", "socks", "shirt", "pants", "tie", "shoes", "jacket")
person5 <- c("underwear", "socks", "shirt", "tie", "pants", "jacket", "shoes")
person6 <- c("underwear", "socks", "pants", "shirt") # Predict next events
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Using the markovchain package we can estimate the next state given the current state using the estimated transition matrix.  First create an n x 2 matrix `m` of transition pairs (one per row) and then perform the estimation giving `est`.  From that we can form our prediction using `predict` and `plot` the transition matrix.

```
library(markovchain)

L <- list(person1, person2, person3, person4, person5)
m <- do.call("rbind", lapply(L, function(x) cbind(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1))))
mc <- markovchainFit(m)
est <- mc$estimate

est # show transition matrix
# ...snip...

# estimate next step after "shirt"
person6 <- c("underwear", "socks", "pants", "shirt")
prior_state <- tail(person6, 1)
predict(est, prior_state)
## [1] tie 

plot(est)
```

(continued after plot)

[image: screenshot]

A variation of the above is to consider the distribution conditional on no state that has appeared appearing again.  Here `allowed` is those states that do not appear in `person6`.  The prediction in this case is still `"tie"` but had the prediction from the original markov chain above been a state that occurred in person6 then the prediction would have been different.  This prediction no longer has the markov property since the prediction of the next state depends on all states that have occurred so far.

```
allowed <- setdiff(states(est), person6)
names(which.max(conditionalDistribution(est, tail(person6, 1))[allowed]))
## [1] "tie"
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! If I wanted more than one possibility for the next entry, is there an option to output the possibilities and their associated probabilities?

Comment: Try `conditionalDistribution(est, prior_state)` where `est` and `prior_state` are defined in the answer.  That will give you the probability to each state from `prior_state`.  If what you meant was that you want a prediction for each of several prior states then try `sapply(c("shirt", "pants"), predict, object = est)`  Suggest you read through the help files and vignettes of the package.

Comment: conditionalDistribution() is exactly what I was looking for. One more question -- the model seems to predict the next event based on only the immediately preceding event. For example, if I edit the training sequences to end with either "jacket" if "socks" appears in the sequence or end with "coffee" if it does not, then predict based on c("underwear", "pants", "shirt", "shoes"), the model still predicts "jacket" with high probability. I assume this is because I'm only using the last event as the state argument, but it doesn't seem to take a vector. Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe this is more of a sequence mining problem?

Comment: That is how Markov chains work.  The next state depends only on the prior state.  (You can create a new chain whose set of states is made up of pairs of original states so that for example `socks-pants` is a state in the new chain but then you will need a lot more data in order to estimate it.) At any rate,this is a standard model and there are numerous accounts of it such as the reference in the markovchain package documentation which you can read if you would like to use markov chains to model this.

Comment: Have added a variation which excludes states that have already occurred from being predicted again.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is definitely more a graph / markov chain type of problem than what you call time series. 
My guess would be value you should expect is "tie", "shoes", "jacket"

All vectors have the same elements "underwear", "socks", "pants", "shirt", "tie", "shoes", "jacket" occurring once.
You can set logical constraints about the order (you can not tie a tie without putting on a shirt first same for the jacket)
3 out of the 5 person presents the 3 elements in the order "tie", "shoes", "jacket"

I would be very interested in a formal general solution of such problems !